# Proof of equivalence of two definitions of an orthonormal basis on a Hilbert space

Tags: hilbert-spaces, definition, orthonormal

The following are two equivalent definitions of an orthonormal basis $\mathcal{B}$ on   a Hilbert space $H$:

1. $\mathcal{B}$ is orthonormal and complete ($\mathcal{B}$ is dense in $H$).
2. if $\langle v, b\rangle = 0$ for all $b\in \mathcal{B}$ and some $v\in H$, then $v=0$.

---

I was wondering where I could find a proof of the above equivalence, since it is stated in my notes without any demostration.

Comment: What does complete mean in this context? Dense? It's not fully clear

Comment: Also, it seems to me that the second condition doesn't imply orthonormal, because for example in $\ell^2$, I could just scale the canonical basis up by two